# Get rid of black lines in PDF export

Tags: qgis, pdf

When I export to PDF, I get some black lines either vertical or horizontal.
It's exported in 300 DPI and I have used QGIS 2.8.

[image: see example i attached picture]

Comment: QGIS 2.8 is super old. You should consider upating to QGIS 3.x or at least 2.18 if you need to keep v2 for some reason.